# Duplicate codes in Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I am currently working on one project. It may potentially have duplicated codes in multiple controllers like below.

---

Controller A

```
class A: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    // about 50~70 lines of codes
    @IBAction func scanButtonTapped {
        // used self (as AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate)
        // used view
        // called presentViewController(...), which is a func in UIViewController
    }
}
```

---

Controller B

```
class B: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    @IBAction func scanButtonTapped {
        // will need same logic as in Controller A
    }
}
```

---

My current solution is have another class C, and move the duplicated codes into it. However, if I do so, controller can cast to `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`, but not to `UIViewController`.

```
class C {
    func btnTapped (view: UIView, controller: AnyClass) {
        // logic is here
        // controller can cast to AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
        // but controller cannot cast to UIViewController
    }
}
```

so A and B will have

```
class A {
    @IBAction func scanButtonTapped {
        let c = C()
        c.btnTapped(view, self)
    }
}
```

---

My question is if it is possible to cast controller into `UIViewController`. OR is there another way to refactor the codes properly?

Comment: why dont you do `class C: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate { ... }` and then `class A : C {` and `class B : C {`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about extend AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate protocol and create default implementation by protocol extension (POP approach)?

```
protocol ScanButtonClickable: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func btnTapped() // this line is optional
}

extension Clickable where Self: UIViewController {
    func btnTapped() {
        // logic is here
    }
}

class A: UIViewController, ButtonClickable {
...
}

class B: UIViewController, ButtonClickable {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, JMI. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//declare your default method to be used across classes
protocol MyProtocol {
   func myFunc()
}

//provide the implementation of your default behavior here in myFunc()
extension MyProtocol {
    func myFunc() {
       print("Default behavior")
 }
}

class A: MyProtocol {

}

class B: MyProtocol {

}

let a = A()
a.myFunc()

let b = B()
b.myFunc()

//prints
Default behavior
Default behavior
```